# Piece of clothing Kakashi wears under his grey Anbu flack jacket

Tags: naruto, merchandise

Does anyone know the name of the clothes that Kakashi wears under his grey Anbu flack jacket? You know, with the mask attached to it.

It looks a little like a tank top.

I would like to buy one, so places to buy or links would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying clothing

Comment: Reopened as per http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/595/27

Answer (score 1):

It's categorized as a [Jockey](https://www.amazon.co.jp/EnzeruFashion-NARUTO%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88-%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E5%A4%89%E8%A3%85-%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0-CSP0007-XXXL/dp/B01DZHPHEI/ref=sr_1_28?s=hobby&ie=UTF8&qid=1481001715&sr=1-28) or [Vest](https://www.amazon.co.jp/CosplayHut-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD/dp/B00G3BRY2C/ref=sr_1_39?s=hobby&ie=UTF8&qid=1481001715&sr=1-39), according to their respective sales listing on Amazon. However, [a Google search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%9A%97%E9%83%A8%E3%83%99%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj82Njg697QAhXGvbwKHV3bDfUQ_AUICCgB&biw=1536&bih=758) returns more relevant results when searching for '暗部ベスト'. Also, [on Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1254408687), Japan's Yahoo Answers, it is referred to as a 'vest'.

You can get it from Amazon Japan [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E5%93%81-cos-hyrz-12-%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89-cos-hyrz-12-%E6%9A%97%E9%83%A8%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B7-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%91%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B7-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B7-%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%85-XXL/dp/B01N3Q6WGS/ref=sr_1_13?s=hobby&ie=UTF8&qid=1481001388&sr=1-13&th=1). Use a shipping forwarding service like [Tenso](http://www.tenso.com/en/) if you live outside Japan.